# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #3](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/election/3) on Arduino has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Juraj]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/election/3) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5480227732979712).

Comment: thank you to everyone who voted for me

Answer (score 5):

A big congratulations goes out to Juraj. Woohoo!

It is a well deserved win. You already do a lot for this community and now you get the diamond recognition for it. I know that the Arduino community is in very good hands.

Congratulations!

Comment: +1 There is too much trash on ARD.SE for one moderator to handle :)